# Database design - best practices

Tags: database, entity-framework, database-design

I am creating a website where the user has the possibility to upload content (pictures, videos pdf's etc.).

Each type of content has a different number of properties with corresponding values.

I have thought about making this design:

[image]

Is this the right way to do it?

Since each type of property has a predetermined set of property-names, should I make a relation between the two? Or would it be fine to handle this in code instead?

Comment: It is useless to ask advise about data base schema. To make a good schema developer should know all smallest bussiness details. For example  It seems to me that you don't need at least 2 tables or maybe 3 but I don' t know anything  about the real situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the options for storing hierarchical data in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database)

Comment: Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1):

Normally in a relational database you should use columns to model the attributes of an entity.  So "Plan A" is to create PictureContent, PDFContent, etc tables in the database.

The design you are proposing is called [Entity-Attribute-Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) or EAV.  It has some pretty serious drawbacks, but it is occasionally useful, typically when data sizes are moderate and you need change your metadata at runtime.

If you *do* need a dynamic schema, consider using JSON instead of EAV, which can easilly be serialized into .NET objects, or accessed dynamically.